# Yii 1.* : how to get all relative table data as an array

Tags: yii

my db query :

```
        $enqModel = EnquiryDetail::model();

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->together = true;

        $criteria->with = array(
            'courseOffered',
            'courseOffered.course' => array('alias'=>'coc'),
            'courseSuggesteds',
            'courseSuggesteds.course' => array('alias'=>'csc'),
            'courseTakens',
            'courseTakens.course' => array('alias'=>'ctc'),
            'courseOffered.course.stream' => array('alias'=>'cos'),
            'courseSuggesteds.course.stream' => array('alias'=>'css'),
            'courseTakens.course.stream' => array('alias'=>'cts'),
            'org',
            'branch',
            'attendances',
            'heardAbout',
            'mode',
            'enrolledBy',
            'followups',
            'followups.followupsBy' => array('alias'=>'followups_by'),
            'batchStudents',
            'batchStudents.batch' => array('alias'=>'batch'),
            'batchStudents.batch.batchDays' => array('alias'=>'batch_days'),
            'paymentsPlans' => array('alias'=>'emiPlans')
        );
        $result = $enqModel->findAllByAttributes(array('enquiry_id'=>$enqId),$criteria);


        return $result;
```

now i want it return all as an array for restApi so i will pass only id and it will return all the relative data as an array.

problem is when i do findAll or findAllByAttributes is shows all result but when i try to pass it as CJSON::enode only parent tables data get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please you can try this below code:

Following Changes in YII Framework file.

File Path : **../yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php**

**CActiveRecord.php** (Add code line no :- 1871)

```
/**
* @return CMapIterator the iterator for the foreach statement
*/
public function getIterator()
{
       $attributes=$this->getAttributes();
       $relations = array();

       foreach ($this->relations() as $key => $related)
       {
               if ($this->hasRelated($key))
               {
                       $relations[$key] = $this->$key;
               }
       }

       $all = array_merge($attributes, $relations);

       return new CMapIterator($all);
}
```

after you can try your code and get all relative table data as an array.

Comment: Thank Nikunj.
It works fine with findByAttrubutes but findAll,findAllByAttributes and one more thing any changes in framework is not a good idea so i create a class in components and i write your function into that.